# BIRT dynamic query through script issue

Tags: eclipse, extjs, birt

I have to generate PDF report on click of a button from browser.

I am sending Ajax request to a controller[Ajax request has dynamic parameters to be passed into Report] 
Controller creates a map and generates report.

I am able to get preview of the grid on the BIRT preview.

I am using **beforeRead** under **script section of DataSet**.

I have tried printing query on a file from beforeRead itself and it looks ok.

But i am getting some error on browser console: says **syntax error : (%PDF-1.5**

Comment: *beforeOpen not beforeRead